# How do I list [Environment] members to expose UserName?

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I needed to know how to get the current username and so a quick search produced the following single PowerShell line

```
[Environment]::UserName
```

Sweet.

I then got curious as to what else is tucked away in `[Environment]`.

Another search suggested the syntax `<any object> | Get-Member` so I typed

```
[Environment] | Get-Member
```

Progress! That produced a long list of methods and properties. `UserName` wasn't among them.

So what exactly is `[Environment]::UserName` and how can I get a list of similar special nonmember/nonproperty creatures if they exist?

That question led me typing `[Environment]` on a line by itself. That exposed a few tidbits including its BaseType is `System.Ojbect`.

I then thought to retry the `<object> | Get-Member` syntax, i.e.,

```
System.Object | Get-Member
```

to see if that would show `[Environment]` as some type of object but the line erred out.

Why did `Get-Member` divulge details about `[Environment]` but not `System.Object`?

Comment: `Get-Member -Static`

Comment: `[Environment].GetMembers()` and you may want to pipe that to `|?{$_.MemberType -eq 'Property'}`

Comment: There's also the `env:` PowerShell provider drive.

Comment: Oh, and you can look up the [class definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment(v=vs.100).aspx) for System.Environment from the .Net Framework.

Comment: Thanks @PetSerAl - That answers what exactly [Environment]::UserName is and why Get-Member didn't initially return it.  

I'm still wondering why calling Get-Member on System or System.Object erred out.